# DynamoDB - Is Remove on List a linear or constant-time op? or does it matter (for consistency or compute)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

My Question is about the time complexity for a [DynamoDB `REMOVE` on a List](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE)...

- I know that DynamoDB operations are abstracted from the client (e.g.
  `boto3` in an AWS Lambda or EC2), within DynamoDB itself - but
  regardless still, **do DynamoDB operations' runtime complexity affect
  [Read Consistency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html), or affect runtime of the compute that calls
  DynamoDB ops (e.g. Lambda/EC2)?**
- I also know that (in general complexity-theory) removing an element
  from an ordered-list or array, such that the list/array elements that
  are subsequent/following the removed element shift by 1 [to the left]
  to replace the otherwise [null/empty] gap left at the removed
  element's original index/location, is a linear O(n) procedure:  All
  those following elements must shift, and the number of them is on the
  order of O(n).

The end result of that (the following-elements shifting to cover gap), is also what in particular happens to result on a [DynamoDB List after a `REMOVE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE) op on it [per DynamoDB implementation] - but **I don't know for a fact what the DynamoDB-internal time-complexity for `REMOVE` on a list is:  Is it O(n), or O(1)?**

Whatever it is, "why does it matter, if the operation is DynamoDB-internal"?  Below are reasons why (if they are correct):

- If DynamoDB is being called synchronously* [and not asynchronously], then the client waits for DynamoDB to finish/return, and therefore the DynamoDB runtime adds to the client's runtime
- I'm not 100% sure if DynamoDB runtime for an op affects Read Consistency of the data operated on - **is Read Consistency degraded the longer that a DynamoDB op takes to complete?**  [fwiw, I would infer, yes it would degrade]

fwiw I am curious about these questions, as I am trying to decide whether or not to call `REMOVE` to benefit from it not leaving a gap, or implement something that can instead tolerate gaps.

*I think `boto3` itself, for example, makes synchronous DynamoDB calls (although calling asynchronous with python still, is maybe possible with project(s) like [aiobotocore](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore) or [aioboto3](https://pypi.org/project/aioboto3/)).

Comment: The answer is we don't know. If it's really significant to you, your best option is likely to be to time various scenarios and decide if there's a consistent behavior that you can rely on and then program accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

When you perform any action (other than a read) it will be counted as a write action.

Remember that writes are counted in per 1kb, this is how credits are used so the write speed **should** be spread evenly across the pool of credits that exist. You would see the write time change when partitions are uneven or credits are depleted.

A difference in time from the SDK would be larger volumes, at this point you're restricted by Network transit so you might say that would be **linear** rather than **constant**.

For DynamoDB the `UpdateItem` action is a write action which means the service needs to update this on each node across all availability zones, when you read it will read from one of these nodes.

By default the SDK will use eventual [consistency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html) which means that it will not care for the most accurate answer, it will query against one of these nodes and accept that as a true answer (even if another node has a more recent answer).

Bare in mind that this process is does in milliseconds (I believe potentially upto a second).

**Additional input into AWS services methodology**

AWS have a general methodology (although I **cannot confirm** if this is how DynamoDB has been implemented behind the scenes). In fact the way that most (if not all) AWS services are designed and developed is that they have multiple layers. This has been confirmed for EC2 and Route 53.

The first layer (**control plane**) acts as a medium to validate the request is ok, it does this by running the same validations as the service layer i.e. syntax, values etc but it does not perform the action. A successful or unsuccessful response is handed back.

The SDK receives this and your code continues, this first layer meanwhile hands to the service layer (**data plane**) to attempt to do this (with a repeat in case it fails). This service layer performs the action and hopefully succeeds.

If you're interested you should watch the [Beyond five 9s: Lessons from our highest available data planes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2L1S0zfnIzo) video from RE:Invent.

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm not sure that your general description of a control plane that pre-validates a request and provides a response to the client prior to the actual operation being performed, if that's what you mean, is correct, especially in the case of a DynamoDB update. Doubtless some preliminary parameter validation could potentially be performed in this way. Do you have documentation that supports this?

Comment: Its in the video attached @jarmod. This is how AWS build their APIs for resiliency :)

Comment: And heres a list of operations for DynamoDB by the plane the true operation occurs at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.API.html @jarmod

Comment: The video segment that you're referring to is the one entitled Modular Separation beginning around 31:25, which Colm indicates is used for Route53 and IAM, and perhaps others. I don't see any evidence this is part of the design of DynamoDB.

Comment: Hi @jarmod, point understood that it does not explicitly state. I have tidied up the answer which I hope makes this clear for the OP